# Beer brewing formula question - solving for the wrong thing

Tags: linear-algebra

I am brewing beer at home and I am having trouble with a formula. I know the formula for how to solve for how much water is left in the kettle after boiling the wort; however, this formula isn't much use to me, as I know how much beer I want to make.

What I need to know is how much water to put into the pot to compensate for the loss of water during the boil.

I need to solve for the TotalAmountWater not the TotalWaterLeft. Can someone help me solve this? I haven't taken math in decades and am lost.

TotalWaterLeft = (.96* TotalAmountWater) - (TotalAmountWater * EvaportationRate * LengthOfBoil * 0.016)

Comment: It seems you're solving for an equation. To start off, you have evaporation rate and length of boil...maybe you could start off by sharing with us how long will you boil the water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$TWL=0.96\cdot TAW-TAW \cdot ER \cdot LOB \cdot 0.016 \implies TAW(0.96-ER\cdot LOB\cdot 0.016)=TWL \implies TAW=\dfrac {TWL}{(0.96-ER\cdot LOB\cdot 0.016)}$

This last one formula gives you the answer if $.96$ is $0.96$?

Give us some beer!

Comment: Thank you both so much. That works great. I knew my math was wrong. My numbers were coming out way off when I tried...  totalWater = ((.96 - (.016*evapRate*boilLength)) / desiredWater ) /1;

Answer (score 2):

Let $W_i$ be the amount of water we started with, $W_f$ the amount of water left at the end, $r$ the evaporation rate, $t$ the amount of time the water is boiled. Then you want to solve $$W_f=.96W_i-.016W_irt$$ for $W_i$ in terms of the other variables. Well, $$.96W_i-.016W_irt=(.96-.016rt)W_i,$$ so $$W_i=\frac{W_f}{.96-.016rt}.$$ Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you both so much. That works great.